# Single source from multiple headers

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm writing solutions for codeforces and codechef platforms and both requires a single source file submission. I wrote few headers with functions utility functions that I use here and there in my solution.

Is there an automatic tool that given multiple source files is able to generate a compilable single source copying in it only the referenced functions from the provided includes?

As an example given the following three files (A,B,C):

**file A:**

```
void funcA1(...)
void funcA2(...)
void funcA3(...)
```

**file B:**

```
void funcB1(...)
void funcB2(...)
void funcB3(...)
```

**file C:**

```
void funcC1(...){ ... funcA3()}
void funcC2(...)
void funcC3(...)
```

I would like to have

**main:**

```
void funcA2(...)
void funcA3(...) //referenced by C1
void funcC1(...) 
void funcB1(...) 
int main(){
...
funcA2();
funcB1();
funcC1();
}
```

Comment: I have never heard of any such tool.  A need for such a thing is unusual, as ordinarily one would either build a library containing the reusable functions or just give all the sources to the compiler.  And you *need* a compiler to determine automatically which functions are referenced.  I think your best bet is to arrange your functions so that it is easy to do the job by hand.

Comment: It's a very specific need that I'm sure is not available. But you can use a python script to do that. Manipulating a text file with python is very easy and if you have very big amount of file to process it is worth it.

Comment: I was checking for any existing tools before to start writing such script myself. I ended up writing ~1k lines of utility functions and copy-n-paste manually is tedious and error-prone. I will write it in Haskell and post the gist here. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Curiously, we are discussing how to write a tool that compilers do in every build: merge files.

Comment: I can access the merged version of the sources (preprocessor stage using `-E` option in `g++` for instance). But the preprocessor basically appends the content of all the includes regardless of what portion of code is really used.